# pear write() function doesn't unload all rows

Tags: php, excel, pear

When I try to unload data to excel file with `Spreadhset_Excel_Writer` library, it doesn't unload more than 10-15 rows..

```
$worksheet->write($line, 1, $row['line'],$fmt_text_mid);  //this row is unload to excel file
```

So, why this library doesn't upload more than 10-15 rows, what is wrong here?!

Comment: And what actually happens if $line is > 10-15? Does it give you an error? Does it write anything to your logs? Does it create an invalid file? does it set your server on fire?

Comment: when I try to unload $row['line'] to txt file it work, it's unloaded. but when I try it in wrtie($row['line']) function it's doesn't unload more  than 10 rows. Are there any constraints in the library to memory? I mean there are several columns that all information is completely discharged, until the end, but there are only numbers. namely, in this column is discharged a lot of text, but not until the end of